# How to correctly use nginx try_files in proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I am trying to use try_files in nginx proxy_pass.
If I type h--p://example.com/admin1/SisrAZbCCnisI and don't use try_fiels than everything works.

- [INFO] dart: GET /admin1/SisrAZbCCnisI= 9ms 200
- [INFO] dart: GET /admin1/SisrAZbCCnisI = 63ms 200

If I type wrong url then I get a 404 error.

- [INFO] dart: GET /admin1 12ms 404
- [INFO] dart: GET /admin1/ 12ms 404
- [INFO] dart: GET /admin1/wrongstring 12ms 404

and when I try to use try_files always I get and default index.html.

How to correctly use nginx try_files in proxy_pass?

**UPDATE:** 
Error page and the index.html is working. Only my proxy_pass is not working. still shows the index.default when I type /adnin1/***

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

server {
    charset UTF-8;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  my.example.com;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # redirect error pages to the static page
    error_page 401 402 403 405 404  /index.html;
    location = /index.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /index.html;
    location = /index.htm {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files (beginning with a period)
    location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
    }

   if ($host = my.example.com/admin1) {
         return 301 https://my.example.com$request_uri;
   }

   if ($host = my.example.com/admin2) {
         return 301 https://my.example.com$request_uri;
   }

}

server {
    charset UTF-8;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    server_name  my.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    # redirect mobile app to
    location /admin1 {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
        proxy_connect_timeout 1;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }

    # redirect mobile app to
    location /admin2 {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
        proxy_connect_timeout 1;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }

    # redirect error pages to the static page
    error_page 401 402 403 405 404  /index.html;
    location = /index.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /index.html;
    location = /index.htm {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files (beginning with a period)
    location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
    }

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ )
    {
    return 404;
    } 

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `try_files` and `proxy_pass` in the same `location` block. `try_files` is only concerned with the existence or not of a local file.

Comment: My proxy_pass direct to dart server which serves a api. How can I send admin1 and all the path like admin1/* to my proxy and rest inculding the all the error (400, 401, 401, 402, 403, 404...) to default index.html?

Comment: If you are trying to intercept errors from the service on port 3000, you will need to add `proxy_intercept_errors on;`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) for details.

Comment: No, the api handles the error. If user types other than admin1 or admin1/* I get and error. I need to handle these error.

Comment: @RichardSmith, I update my code. Only proxy_pass part is not working. Any idea?